# Proving that a commutative ring where an ascending chain of ideals has at most 3 ideals is isomorphic to a product of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

I'm working on an problem which states:

Given that the commutative ring $R$ has the property that every strictly increasing chain of ideals consists of at most $3$ ideals, show that $R$ is isomorphic to $K \times L$ where $K$ and $L$ are fields.

I don't really see how to get started with this problem. I know that I have to show that there exists a ring isomorphism between $R$ and $K \times L$ but I don't see exactly how to do this. As any strictly increasing chain of ideals has at most $3$ ideals, I am tempted to say that $R$ is a noetherian ring. Is this correct?

Can someone provide some insight and additional help with this problem?

Comment: "of length at most 3" $\to$ "has at most 3 elements"

Comment: As it is currently stated, it is certainly not true. Just think of the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}/(4)$.

Comment: I believe what is meant by the length of the chain of ideals is that any chain of strictly increasing ideals has no more than 3 ideals in the chain. That is that they are of the form $I_1 \subset I_2 \subset I_3$. Does this change anything?

Comment: @MathsBBB No it doesn't. Did you read Andreas's comment? It gives an example of a ring such that ALL the ideals are just $\{0\}=I_1\subseteq I_2\subseteq I_3=R$ and nothing else. No ring that is a product of two or more rings can have their ideals in a line like that.

Comment: Chains are often counted by their *links* rather than link endpoints. It might be something to clarify for sure.

Comment: @MathsBBB based on your comment I took the liberty of rephrasing your question to avoid ambiguity in the length of a chain. Feel free to revert if this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

（Sorry for my bad English.）

First for avoiding  Andreas Caranti's example $\mathbb{Z}/p^2\mathbb{Z}$ and all fields, we need more condition that there are at least 4 ideals of $R$.

By the above assumption we take different ideals  $I,J$ not $(0),(1)$.
Now $I,J$ don't have  inclusion.
Trivially $I$ is a maximal ideal, and $R/I$ is a field. Similarly $R/J$ is a field.

Now considering the chain $(0)\subset I\cap J \subset I$ and $J\nsubseteq I $, we have $I\cap J=(0)$.
Similarly by $I\subset I+J\subset (1)$, $I+J=(1)$.
So by Chinese remainder theorem, we have $R\cong R/I\cap J\cong R/I\times R/J$.